# how add multiple unrelated directories to GIT repository

Tags: linux, git

I have multiple directories/files all over disc, which are logically bounded and I would like them in one git repository. Sadly I cannot move them to one common directory, as different 3.party program looks for them in their respective locations and sometime changes them. Which I would like to track/version.

I also have other git repositories here and there all over disc.

I would like to put in one repository something like

```
/etc/conf.d/myprog.*
/usr/bin/myprog.sh
/home/myname/somedir/myprog/*
/home/myname/otherdir/myprog/*
```

while NOT HAVE in there all other directories (so put .git and long .gitignore in / would not be a good idea)

Some could be done with symlinks on place of original files, but there are more *-like expressions, where I cannot force other programs from creating/deleting files there, so symlinks do not help

One possible way is to create some separete git dir and scripts to copy everything there (and delete no longer existing files) before commit and copy (and delete) from there after each checkout, but it is not elegant, the data are huge/many and it means duplicity with all its problems.

Is there more elegant way?

(something like make dirs for each area with .gitignore inside it and something like .git_real_path file containing the real path on the disc, where tis should be applied)

Comment: AFAIK there's no *elegant* way to do this; git is designed only to work with single directories, and trying to use a single git repository across the entire file system definitely does not fall into the scope of what git tries to do.

Comment: The only(?) elegant way is to create a `/home/username/my-programs/` catalog, put all programs there, create a git repo out of it, and symlink these programs to other locations all over the system. If it is not possible to make those symlinks, then think of something to make it possible.

Comment: I think the only way is to create a repo for each folder and to use submodules. https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules

Comment: I am thinking of creating hardlinks to those directories as subdirs of git repository. This way I could have .gitignore in main dir somewhere and the dirs with files could be part of more git repositories. I am only not sure about consequencies of having such duplicated dirs on filesystem, but probably it should be OK if I do not any cycle here.